# Binding property from viewModel

Tags: c#, mvvm, datagrid, viewmodel

Good Morning, I have a problem with a page in C#, on a customer server. 
I have a page divided in 2 parts: on the left there is a list of objects and on the right there is a table which shows the details of the selected object. Among the fields shown on the right there is a link to one or more files (related to the object) the user can download. Based on some conditions, I want to prevent some users to download these files and let them only see the name of the files.

In the xaml I created a DataGrid to show the details of the objects defined as follows:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Name="dgRPD" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" CanUserReorderColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding ListRPD}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedRPD}" Height="Auto">
```

The code for the column is the following:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Files" Width="Auto" >
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <cc:FilePickerOnlyName CanChooseFile="False" FileName="{Binding Path=FileNameDoc}" FilePath="{Binding Path=PathDoc, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" IsEnabled="{Binding hide, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" DataContext="{Binding}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

My idea was using the IsEnabled property to achieve my goal, and if a set it to False I get it. Therefore, I created a property "hide", defined as follows:

```
private bool _hide;
public bool hide
{
    get { return _hide; }
    set
    {
        if (_hide != value)
        {
            _hide = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("hide");
        }
    }
}
```

To try this approach, I set hide as false at the inizialization of the ViewModel and every time I change the selected object in the left side of the page and manually force the RaisePropertyChange for hide. 
I do not have problems retrieving the list of objects or the details of the objects, just when I try to disable the fields. I googled and searched for any variations on the Path of the isEnabled Binding but nothing worked.
How can i solve this?

Comment: Note that the `visual-studio` tag should _only_ be used for questions relating to the Visual Studio IDE, not code merely written using it. If you are trying to tag a specific version of the C# language, or .NET, please add the relevant tag for that (as this is what determines how you write your code, and execute it, respectively).

Comment: Ok John, thank you for your tip.

Comment: Use `Snoop` - https://github.com/cplotts/snoopwpf - and find the `IsEnabled` value, it should tell you what's going on. If you don't know how to use it, let me know and we open a chat :)

Comment: Your `hide` property has to be in each corresponding item not in the VM of the Window/UserControl - in case you have this wrong.

Comment: Thought about this too... but without the whole VM we can't see what he is binding to the `Datacontext`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of a coworker I fixed the issue; I changed the IsEnabled as follows:

```
IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=root, Path=ViewModel.hide}"
```

and in the UserControl tag at the beginning of the XAML I added the following lines:

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:[namespace of the ViewModel]"
x:Name="root"
```

and now it works. Answering the comments of @Blacktempel and @Juan Carlos Rodriguez, the hide property was declared as a public bool in the ViewModel but not directly related to the objects of the left columns or the details of the objects in the right part of the page because in both cases they are part of a very big and complicated external class whose source code I can not access or modify. I also wanted to mimize the changes needed to make the program work.